# Using DocumentBuilder to parse HTML response in Java

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache HttpClient to do a POST request and receive a simple HTML page in response. I want to extract few elements from the HttpResponse object, but I do not want to use any third party library.
The simple solution would be to get a String object using `EntityUtils.toString()`

Is there any other approach which does the same in a more refined way. For example, can I parse the web page and do a getElementById()?

I tried with

```
DocumentBuilderFactory respFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder responseBuilder = respFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document responseDoc = responseBuilder.parse(responseEntity.getContent());
Element changeLog = responseDoc.getElementById("ChangeLog");
System.out.println(changeLog.getFirstChild().getNodeValue());
```

But I get a NPE!

The reponse is like follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Content modified /</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Content modified /</h1>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td><div id="Status">200</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message</td>
            <td><div id="Message">OK</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Location</td>
            <td><a href="/" id="Location">/</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Parent Location</td>
            <td><a href="" id="ParentLocation"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Path</td>
            <td><div id="Path">/</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Referer</td>
            <td><a href="" id="Referer"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>ChangeLog</td>
            <td><div id="ChangeLog">&lt;pre&gt;deleted("/content/dam/dlv/images/entity/hotel/yvr/yvr_bwdv_bwdv/yvr_bwdv_bwdv-2.jpg");&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p><a href="">Go Back</a></p>
<p><a href="/">Modified Resource</a></p>
<p><a href="">Parent of Modified Resource</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest to use dedicated parser like Jsoup - It is very flexible and easy to use HTML parser. I supports CSS selectors so you can select proper elements like `input.myClass[type=text]` or by id `select("#idOfElement")` etc.
Sometimes webpages can be corrupted eg. no ending tags etc. Jsoup is lanient in such cases, while XML parser will be not. I use it for a long time and I very satisfied.

http://jsoup.org/

Comment: I did not want to use another library just to parse the response. However, I got my answer.
It seems getElementById doesn't work unless xHTML standards are followed or something like that. Alternative is to use getElementsByTagName and loop though them to check the required id attribute.